# If 2 fermionic atoms form a molecule, will the molecule always behave as a boson?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecules, quantum-statistics

2 fermionic atoms give a bosonic molecule. 2 bosonic atoms form a bosonic molecule. Is there a energy scale where these two molecules will behave differently? If yes, will it depend on the rovibrational level of the molecule? Does the bond length play a role?

A practical example would be $^{39}K_2$ molecule vs $^{40}K_2$ molecule.

$^{39}K_2$ -> Potassium 39 and $^{40}K_2$ -> Potassium 40.

Comment: The question title does not really reflect the question.

Comment: any suggestions?